# Не видит контроллер в роутинге

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация, controller

Вообще не могу вдуплить почему не видно контроллер из роута.

web.php:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@show');
```

app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

По итогу ошибка при переходе на главную:

```
Error
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Controller" not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение, в контроллер добавить:

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
```